# Struct changes after being passed to a pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to make a function that has to create a series of pthreads. I'm trying to keep track of each thread by assigning it a unique int t. However, when I try to make more than one thread, the value of t changes, every time I increment it in the main function. It should be pass by value so why is it changing?

```
// Struct //
typedef struct threadArg {
  int verbose;
  int listSize;
  int thread;
  int (*list)[];
} threadArg;

// In main //
for(t=0; t < numThreads; t++){
    printf("Creating thread %ld...\n", t);
    struct threadArg arg = {
      .verbose = verbose,
      .list = &arr,
      .listSize = size,
      .thread = t
    };
    printf("t: %d\n", (arg.thread));
    status = pthread_create(&threadID[t], NULL, threadSort, (void*)&arg);
    if (status){
      printf("ERROR: failed to create thread", t);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

// Thread Sort function //
void *threadSort(void* arguments) {
  // *** Bubble Sort ***                                                                                                                                                             
  threadArg* arg = (threadArg*) arguments;
  int verbose = arg->verbose;
  int size = arg->listSize;
  int (*arr)[size] = arg->list;
  int t = arg->thread;
  if (verbose & INIT) { printf("Thread %d initalized!\n", t); }
}
```

Thank you for your help,
Wally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It should be pass by value

No, this line passes it "by reference", that is passes the address of `arg`:

```
status = pthread_create(&threadID[t], NULL, threadSort, (void*)&arg)
```

The instance of `arg` in your code is used and destroyed and recreated for each iteration of the loop.

To fix this modfiy you code like follows:

```
void * threadSort(void * arguments);

[...]

  struct threadArg arg = {
    .verbose = verbose,
    .list = &arr,
    .listSize = size,
    .thread = 0,
  };

  struct threadArg args[t] = {0};

  for(t=0; t < numThreads; t++)
  {
    printf("Creating thread %ld...\n", t);
    args[t] = arg;
    args[t].thread = t;
    printf("t: %d\n", arg.thread);
    status = pthread_create(threadID + t, NULL, threadSort, args + t);

    [...]
```

This introduces an array of `struct arg` with an element for each sperate thread, being nitialised by the value of `threadArg`, which is not used elsewhere but to have a common initialisation of whag is being passed to the thread function.

Comment: Ah I see. I thought creating the struct in the loop created separate entities with each go-around. I guess I'm a little rusty when it comes to C. Many thanks!